# Как прописать сетевой интерфейс и его адрес в /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, ip, proxy

Возникла проблема: при поднятии ipv4 прокси (своя сеть /24), пытаюсь прописать виртуальные сетевые интерфейсы вместе с ip адресами на них в /etc/network/interfaces примерно следующим образом:

```
auto eth0:1
ifасе eth0:1 inet static
address 185.187.198.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

После перезгрузки - сервер не хочет загружаться, очевидно файл неверно конфигурирован.

Когда же я делаю это в ручном режиме, то есть выполняю команды типа:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 185.187.198.1
```

Адреса встают на эти интерфейсы и прокси работают соотвественно, но, разумеется, после перезагрузки эти интерфейсы пропадают, а мне нужен постоянный вариант.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, как прописать эти интерфейсы с адресами на них, чтобы постоянно работали, спасибо

PS: вот сам файл /etc/network/interfaces:

GNU nano 2.2.6                Файл: /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 95.215.111.29
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 95.215.111.1
        pointopoint 95.215.111.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Попробовал добавить ip addr add... все равно не хотят адреса добавляться - бестолку, соответственно прокси не работают, что я не так делаю? Вот что щас есть в interfaces:

Все равно не хотят адреса добавляться, я пробую добавить на eth0:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 95.215.111.29
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 95.215.111.1
        pointopoint 95.215.111.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

up ip addr add 185.187.198.1/24 dev eth0
up ip addr add 185.187.198.2/24 dev eth0
up ip addr add 185.187.198.3/24 dev eth0
```

Вывод команды ip a:

```
root@vps57211:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:57:95:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 95.215.111.29 peer 95.215.111.1/32 brd 95.215.111.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 185.187.198.1/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 185.187.198.2/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 185.187.198.3/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe57:9526/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Вывод 3proxy.cfg

```
pidfile /usr/local/etc/3proxy/3proxy.pid
maxconn 100
nscache 65536
timeouts 1 5 30 60 180 1800 15 60
daemon
setgid 65535
setuid 65535
flush

proxy -n -a -p8000 -i185.187.198.1 -e185.187.198.1
proxy -n -a -p8000 -i185.187.198.2 -e185.187.198.2
proxy -n -a -p8000 -i185.187.198.3 -e185.187.198.3
```

Comment: а описание для `eth0` у вас имеется в файле?

Comment: да, есть, добавил в описание проблемы

Answer (score 2):

> eth0:1

т.н. *network interface aliases* в сетевой подсистеме программы *linux* неактуальны уже лет 16-17. ниже я привожу нормальную конфигурацию без этого «тяжёлого наследия». но если хотите, просто дополните конфигурацию *alias-ами*.

---

чтобы добавить ip-адреса после поднятия сетевого интерфейса, можно воспользоваться директивой `up` в секции `iface`, описывающей конфигурацию этого интерфейса. в этой директиве можно перечислить команды, которые будут выполнены после поднятия интерфейса:

```
iface ...
...
up ip a a 185.187.198.1/24 dev $IFACE
```

пояснения:

- использованные сокращения (можно писать и полностью, просто так короче):

  `ip a a` = `ip address add`
- `$IFACE` — одна из переменных, которые можно использовать в командах внутри директив `pre-up`, `up` и т.д.; подробности см. в `man interfaces`.
- по поводу «дополните конфигурацию *alias-ами*» — если вдруг они действительно необходимы (требуются для корректной работы каких-нибудь древнейших программ, типа *ifconfig*), то проще всего указать эти *alias-ы* (в терминологии программы *ip* — метки, *labels*) непосредственно аргументами программы *ip*:

  ```
  ip a a ... label $IFACE:1
  ```

  подробнее — в `man ip-address` (или `man ip`).

Comment: Все равно не хотят адреса добавляться, я пробую добавить на eth0:

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 95.215.111.29
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 95.215.111.1
        pointopoint 95.215.111.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

up ip addr add 185.187.198.1/24 dev eth0
up ip addr add 185.187.198.2/24 dev eth0
up ip addr add 185.187.198.3/24 dev eth0

Comment: как проверяете? программа `ifconfig` тут ничего не покажет. смотрите вывод `ip a`.

Comment: добавил вывод ip a

Comment: добавил вывод 3proxy.cfg

Comment: в выводе `ip a` адреса, как вы видите, присутствуют.

Comment: тогда в чем проблема может быть? Приложил вывод 3proxy.cfg, прокси-сервер рабочий

Comment: то есть, у вас совершенно другая проблема, не имеющая отношения к текущему вопросу, и связанная с какой-то там программой. лучше задать новый вопрос.

Comment: Все, я решил проблему, в качестве айпи адреса прокси использовал айпишник самого сервака, забыв что он тут не при чем, Александр, вам большое спасибо